# Url masking through htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lithium

I was trying to setup Lithium Php framework. I followed the [documentation](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/getting-started/installation.wiki) for getting started. 
I have done this: *"make sure mod_rewrite is enabled, and the AllowOverride directive is set to 'All' on the necessary directories involved. Be sure to restart the server before checking things."*
Rewrite module is enabled. Verified by

```
apache2ctl -M
```

I have changed the AllowOverride in */etc/apache2/sites-available/default* file.
Now when I go to *http://localhost/LithiumTestApp/*, the page loads but sans css, js, images etc as the links do not work.
I can't seem to find what I have done wrong.

I'm running Apache2 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Edit: Contents of .htaccess are:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$   webroot/   [L]
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Part of Lithium Framework itself. I haven't changed anything here.

Comment: What are the contents of the .htaccess file? Something is getting rewritten somewhere ...

Comment: How did you set it up? Did you clone it from the repo? The main framework repo or the core repo? What do you get when you try to browse directly to an asset? An Apache error or something else?

Comment: Cloned the main framework. git clone git://github.com/UnionOfRAD/framework.git my_app

I can access http://localhost/LithiumTestApp/app/webroot/css/debug.css but the link http://localhost/lithblog/css/debug.css doesn't work.

Comment: I don't follow. How do you get an expected path of localhost/lithblog/ from an install path of localhost/LithiumTestApp/app?

Comment: Sorry! LithBlog was from another test app that I am fiddling with. Consider that as http://localhost/LithiumTestApp/css/debug.css

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend first checking to see if your rewrite is working properly.
I usually set a rewrite log path in my vhost file (or set it in your httpd.conf or apache2.conf, whichever your OS uses).

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 5
```

Then do:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
```

That will allow you to see the log contents while it's happening and refresh the page and see if everything is in order. I also recommend having a look at your Apache error log to see if there are errors in the request.

Also, make sure your resources folder has write permission.